# Why isn't woff2 in the mimetype directory?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, woff, woff2

I see support for woff2 in the Chromium source code but I don't see the mimetype registered with the IANA.

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

> Think about the correct mime type for WOFF 2.0 files (Google uses font/woff2. W3C recommends application/font-woff2)

https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a

Am I missing something obvious or did this just not happen and people are implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct MIME type for `.woff` and `.woff2` font files are [`font/woff`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/font/woff) and [`font/woff2`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/font/woff2) respectively.

It is important to note that even as `application/font-woff` may still have support, it has been deprecated in favour of `font/woff`.

References: [IANA on application media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application), [IANA on font media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#font), and [IETF RFC 8081](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8081).